# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "end_time"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

New to postgresql and even newer to jsonb. I am trying to filter an array of objects:

```
[{"event_slug":"test_1","start_time":"2014-10-08","end_time":"2014-10-12"},
{"event_slug":"test_2","start_time":"2013-06-24","end_time":"2013-07-02"},
{"event_slug":"test_3","start_time":"2014-03-26","end_time":"2014-03-30"}]
```

My Query:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM   locations l
     , jsonb_array_elements(l.events) e
WHERE  l.events @> '{"event_slug":"test_1"}'
AND    e->>'end_time'::timestamp >= '2014-10-30 14:04:06 -0400'::timestamptz;
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "end_time"
LINE 5: AND    e->>'end_time'::timestamp >= '2014-10-30 14:04:06 -04...
                   ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an operator precedence issue: `::` binds more tightly than `->>` does. So you need parentheses.

```
e->>'end_time'::timestamp
```

becomes

```
(e->>'end_time')::timestamp
```